# Edge gestures on iOS

Tags: ios, gesture, ergonomics

I currently have an Android powered phone but I am considering obtaining an iPhone in the future. Of course, there are multiple precautions I'd like to address first.

One of these is ergonomics. On my Android phone I have an application inatalled that allows me to swipe from the edge of the screen to perform some (configurable) actions - for example horizontal swipe from the edge to the center of the screen allows me to go back, swiping diagonally downwards allows me to go to the home screen, etc. This saves me a lot of time and is way more comfortable than stretching my palm all the way to the bottom to perform these actions.

Is there a similar function for iOS, either built-in or available through a third-party application?

Comment: You might want to take a look at custom gestures in Assistive Touch.  I don’t believe there are any custom gesture apps  However, I think you’ll find a Shortcuts a much more efficient system especially when integrated with Siri

Comment: I looked up more information about the aforementioned Shortcuts and it seems to be an application which allows you to automate some things - did I get the correct reference in your comment? If so, I'm afraid this is different to what my question was since the gestures I'm using are available throughout the entire system regardless of which application you're in. Especially the 'Back' button would be greatly useful I believe since the software button for this on most of iOS is in the upper right corner which I believe is uncomfortable to use especially when operating with right hand.